# Crystal Reports XSD file required?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a new report using the PUSH MODEL to supply data. I am creating a DataTable in my C# code and pushing this to a report using a template.

I have created a report template and an XSD (using DataSet.WriteXmlSchema) and added this to my report using the Database Expert option.

I have since deleted the xsd schema but the report still seems to be working.

I was wondering why this was happening. Is the xsd file stored in the report?

Thanks a lot. Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that crystal keeps the schema stored in the report. You can see this behavior when working connected with a database. If you do some changes to the database schema, it won't reflect in your report, unless you go to the database expert and ask it to update the database schema.

It is a nice feature. Usually I use the database to get its schema and create my report, but I push data to report through a DataTable. By this way, the report don't need to reach the database after development.